# Is there a way to let users know their question has been answered?

Tags: discussion

Around 9 days ago there were a couple of interesting questions added.  Both of these got a reply (from me, in this case), yet looking at the profiles of both users they've never logged on since their initial posting of the question.

Is there a way to suggest that users subscribe to email notifications for when their question is commented on and/or answered?  I assume it's not a default (is it even available?).

It's quite possible that they lost the address of the site (it's easy to forget or get it mixed up).  If I remember right there's no welcome email either, so nothing for them to look at to find their way back.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably too late for people who have already left, but discovering the **email settings** in the Stack Exchange drop-down (top left of screen) was a revelation for me. Users can receive emails (at an interval they determine) describing activity on questions and answers they have contributed.

I found it by accident but I have a very poor record of *RTFM* so that may just be me.

Comment: Thanks! I think newbies need a simple "map" to this site - or at least ones like me do.  Meta, main, chat, finding inbox, etc - it seems I discover things in bits and pieces.  Oh well, my self-esteem probably needed readjusting.

Comment: @Jeni - Good comment wrt newbies wanting a map. Suggest some improvements to the main genealogy.se faq (http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq).